# Fulltext stopllist failing on removed stop word

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I want to be able to do a fulltext search on the word "no", but keep getting an error. Below are the steps:

I created a new stoplist based off the system stoplist, then dropped the word "no" from the stoplist.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST ADSStopList FROM SYSTEM STOPLIST;
ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST ADSStopList DROP 'no' LANGUAGE 'English';
```

I can see "no" has been removed from the stoplist:

```
select w.* 
from sys.fulltext_stoplists l
inner join sys.fulltext_stopwords w on l.stoplist_id = w.stoplist_id
where language = 'English' 
    and l.name = 'ADSStopList' 
    and stopword like '%no%';
```

Stopword results are `another` and `now`.  `no` has been removed.

I run a test using `no` stopword:

```
Select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('no part', 1033, 5, 0)
```

I get error:

```
Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 99
Syntax error near 'PART' in the full-text search condition 'NO PART'.
```

If I remove the word "no" from `sys.dm_fts_parser` function, it succeeds fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I have to put the search string in double quotes.

```
Select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('"no part"', 1033, 5, 0);
```